# Redirecting Classic ASP based on document.referrer

Tags: javascript, redirect, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to redirect the parent window after the pop up is closed. Not a problem, but on one of the pages that calls the pop up, when it redirects it outputs the page into a table.

I know its just my companies horrible design, but to get ride of the bug I thought about just not redirecting IF you're on the problem page.

So, I went ahead and parsed the document.referrer variable and then just have redirect IF the string matches mine. Easy enough right? Nope, syntax is pretty solid, it just doesn't redirect...

```
<script language="javascript">
var prevPageName = ''

function getPageName()
{
    prevPageName = (document.referrer.split('://')[1]).split('/')[2]);      
}

function determineRedirect()
{
    if(prevPageName === "mysalestasks.asp")
        window.opener.document.location.href = "/dashboard";
}

</script>
```

Comment: You don't show if/where you're actually calling these functions - if you're not calling them, there's your problem

Comment: yes, I call them both

Comment: I've decided this is impossible to accomplish, because you can't send client side javascript values back to server side asp. What I need to do is figure out how to navigate back without altering the table. I figured out why it messes with the table, because the pop up is launched from a link inside the table. Giving it a different url than the actually page, so if anyone can understand this. How do I reference "dashboard" page and not the page in the table?

Comment: You can send client side javascript values back to server side asp, you can do it via AJAX posts, or gets.  I dont really understand your whole question, are you trying to create child windows with javascript and then control them?